# 1-1/4" thru I joist above bearing point

Tags: electrical, framing

I'd like to run a lot of circuits along one exterior wall thru 11-7/8" tall I joists. The manufacturers basically say 2" holes need to be 1' away from a bearing point yet their plugs may land directly above a bearing point. There is no chart for smaller than 2" holes. That rim joist area is a nice place to run wire so duct vents won't get in the way of the wire or vice versa. I keep my holes close to the bottom flange so ducting and plumbing can easily pass.

Will drilling two or three sets of 1-1/4"  holes an inch from the bottom flange directly above the load bearing point be kosher or detrimental?

Answer (score 3):

Each truss manufacturer have specific requirements for drilling holes in their joists. You’ll need to verify the JOIST TYPE (structural type based on flange size, species, etc.) and SPAN with the manufacturer and then determine where they allow holes.

However, here is an installation guide

https://www.bc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/UK_Install_Guide_A2.pdf

from Boise-Cascade which I’m sure will be similar to most manufacturer’s installation instructions. If you notice in the upper left hand corner, holes are to be drilled in the center (the neutral axis) and size depends on distance from the support.

These joists are specifically manufactured based on loads, spans, etc. and modifications to the joists should be done to the manufacturer’s instructions....random assumptions about drilling 1 1/4” holes just 1” from the bottom flange is not recommended.

Comment: I'm aware randomly drilling this hole isn't a good idea, but this manufacturer's info sheet doesn't discuss holes smaller than 2", thus the concern for what, if any, recommendations for these smaller sized holes. It's funny that a UK version is more descriptive but also has smaller span charts altogether.  Drilling electrical holes in the middle axis of a joist anywhere near the center of the house is a big no-no because HVAC and plumbing can't go through wires.  I may consider that hand-out's info about up to 1.5" hole anywhere if in middle axis and apply it at rim joist area on end.